# Sending multitiple HTTP 2.0 streams to client using PHP

Tags: php, stream, http2

The mulitple streams method in HTTP 2.0 seems to be very interesting. And I would like to know, if it´s today possible to use with PHP?

It could speed up the php appication by sending different site contents from different database queries.

Edit: My example was meant by using multithreaded synchronized Threads in PHP (there are many good libraries to do this) to get 2 or more site contents at the same time and to send it through (not procedural execution).

Comment: I see you have awarded the bounty but not accepted the answer, have I not addressed part of your question?

Comment: as far as I know, SPDY is an idea of google, but it´s not HTTP 2.0. And it´s also deprecated. It will be removed from major browsers in one year.

Comment: Correct, however the http2 spec was finalized only days ago, and it is based on spdy from google. Hence mod_spdy is as close as you'll come today. http://thenextweb.com/insider/2015/02/18/http2-first-major-update-http-sixteen-years-finalized/

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is possible today at some level. You can [configure mod_spdy with PHP](https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/mod_spdy/php). Allegedly you can advertise SPDY capabilities via a header in the Apache configuration per [this article](https://gagor.pl/2013/12/running-apache-with-mod_spdy-and-php-fpm/).

```
Header set Alternate-Protocol "443:spdy/2"
```

[Compatible browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=spdy) should start to leverage the benefits of SPDY at that point with no changes to your PHP code; however I think that just means you can ditch CSS sprites, CSS / JS file consolidations and domain sharding etc. Essentially all things that would have been done to reduce the number of HTTP queries when optimizing a site with traditional approaches.

As to your actual question,

> sending different site contents from different database queries

One idea to optimize a PHP site with an SPDY-enabled server would be through numerous AJAX requests as they will all be magically trunked over a single HTTP connection (in theory). Again that would take a little testing once you have a mod_spdy server configured with PHP, but based on everything I've read I think it could be the case. See this thread and [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29792/46689) for more.

> ..if you have a highly-interactive AJAX-heavy application with many
>   small queries and updates being shuttled around, SPDY provides an
>   elegant solution to the natural impedance mismatch interactivity and
>   HTTP.

I'm not sure there's an HTTP2 module available, but assume one will be on the way soon. Until then my understanding is mod_spdy is the way to go on Apache. There are also [options for Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_spdy_module.html) and perhaps other servers for a PHP solution.

Comment: mod_spdy is definitely the way to go for a quick implementation in PHP.  This guide shows how to switch from mod_php to mod_fcgid which will handle PHP calls and mod_spdy https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/mod_spdy/php

Comment: Thanks @greg_diesel, that's the one I linked to above as well. After searching around for over an hour last night, I really didn't find much info on the subject. Seems it may be time to spool up a mod_spdy VM and crank out a blog post!

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not HTTP/2 - PHP is capable of support WebSockets, which would allow you to send different site contents from different database queries.

There is a WebSocket library called 'Ratchet' for PHP which may achieve what you are trying to do :)

HTH

Comment: I would like to send different data in one Connection, as specified in HTTP 2.0. But I think you mean to send one websocket/conneciton per data?

Answer (score 0):

The Jetty web server supports HTTP2 and fastCGI to PHP.   For example our main site webtide.com is running wordpress behind jetty.

Note also that the async proxy mechanism used by Jetty means that even if features like HTTP2 push are used, they happen in parallel. eg Jetty might decide to push several associated resources and they will be dispatched to word press asynchronously and in parallel.